# CodePen issue with Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4, codepen

Having a problem with CodePen and Bootstrap 4 , won't render a simple button, yet grid works fine:

```html
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
```

Any help?

https://codepen.io/klasap/pen/OOjVep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you're only pulling in the grid element of the Bootstrap CSS. It would seem that CodePen's existing BS4 is picking the wrong Bootstrap file.

**In your pen**

> https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap-grid.css

Use this CDN of the full Bootstrap instead:

> https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem. Please accept this answer by pressing the tick symbol next to it when you can.